# Unable to create EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE for Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I tried to create external data source that connects current data warehouse with Azure SQL Server.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SqlServerCredentials   
WITH IDENTITY = 'XXXX', Secret = 'XXXXX';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE SQLServerInstance
WITH ( 
    LOCATION = 'sqlserver://XXXXX.database.windows.net',
    PUSHDOWN = ON,
    CREDENTIAL = SQLServerCredentials
);
```

**And I got this error message:**

```
Msg 105056, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE statement failed because the 'TYPE' option is not specified. Specify a value for the 'TYPE' option and try again.
```

Anyone can help me? What will be the TYPE for this? 
SQL Server that I want to connect is Azure SQL Server.

Comment: Are you trying to connect from Azure SQL Data Warehouse? If so, you cannot use Polybase to connect to an instance of SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to connect from Azure SQL DW. Is there any such driver to connect to Azure SQL Server?

Comment: If you're trying to move data between ASDW and ASQL, then either Azure Data Factory (preferred) or Azure Databricks are your best choice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can connect to SQL DB from SQL DW, but it works the other way around using the **RDBMS** `TYPE`, see [CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <data_source_name>  
WITH
(    LOCATION                  = '<prefix>://<path>[:<port>]'
[,   CREDENTIAL                = <credential_name> ]
[,   TYPE                      = BLOB_STORAGE | RDBMS | SHARD_MAP_MANAGER ]
[,   DATABASE_NAME             = '<database_name>' ]
[,   SHARD_MAP_NAME            = '<shard_map_manager>' ]
)
[;]
```

Answer (score 0):

From official documentaiton of [MS Azure SQLDW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest), only HADOOP (to read from ADLS/HDFS) and BLOB Storage types are suported. RDBMS is not supported in SQLDW currently.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <data_source_name>  
WITH
(    LOCATION                  = '<prefix>://<path>[:<port>]'
[,   CREDENTIAL                = <credential_name> ]
[,   TYPE                      =  HADOOP | BLOB_STORAGE]
)
[;]
```